# How many times does React.js instantiate its components when user browses a SPA app?

Tags: javascript, components, reactjs, single-page-application

The title says it all. I'm curious how component instantiation works in React.js when it comes to SPA apps. When the user navigates to a new url ("page") what happens with the components not in use any more? If the user moves back and forth between two pages how many times are the different components going to be instantiated? What about bigger apps when there are many different screens; are all of their components going to be cached somehow?

Comment: The docs discuss this: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html. It doesn't cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rendered *it*, and now you don't render *it*, *it*'s removed, and GC collects *it*.  See WiredPrairie's [link](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html) which explains what *it* constitutes.

This applies at every level:

- routers

  - almost always conditional existence, only what's needed for the route
- tabs, accordions, dropdown list items, etc.

  - varies between:
  - visibility
  - existence
  - partial existence based on scroll position (best perf, most difficult)

    - see 'infinite table' techniques

It's just about tradeoffs; small trees can toggle visibility while larger trees should toggle existence.

Comment: So it seems that if you're moving very fast between two pretty different "pages" (having in mind with different components) you are creating garbage on every click. I'm doing this performance check on a very basic app, so I can't find out if there this could lead to any performance issues with bigger apps.I read some of the "reconciliation" doc, but it didn't give me enlightenment on the subject of component instances (it's more about the DOM manipulations), so thank you for the answers.

Comment: Yeah, it'd create a moderate but expected amount of garbage.  Maybe 150% that of any other SPA framework (likely lower, dom take up a ton of memory).  If you're expecting people to switch back and forth very often between two views, you can use show/hide instead.  Switching performance vs performance when not switching.